# M is torsion iff $ann(M)=\langle a \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $D$ be a PID and M finitely generated D-module. Prove M is torsion iff $Ann(M)=\langle a \rangle$. Is there a module $N$ such that $Ann(N)=\{0\}$?.

Assume $M$ is torsion, this means that for every $m\in M$ there is $a\neq 0$ such that $am=0$. The problem here is that these elements $a$ do not need to be the same, and not necessarily powers of one element.

Now, $D$ is finitely generated, say $\{m_1, \dots, m_n\}$ are the generating elements of $M$. Because  $D$ is a PID, any two elements have a $\gcd$, then exists $\gcd(m_1,\dots, m_n)$. Because $M$ is torsion exists $a$ such that $a\cdot \gcd(m_1,\dots, m_n) =0$. Thus every element in the generating set is killed by an element of the form $ca$ meaning the annihilator is $\langle a \rangle$.

Conversely, assume $Ann(M)=\langle a \rangle$. Then an element of the form $ca$ kills every element in the generating set, thus $M$ is torsion.

Comment: What is $a{}{}$?

Comment: You mean "prove $M$ is torsion iff there exists a nonzero $a\in D$ such that ${\rm Ann}(M)=\langle a\rangle$." Have you had any thoughts on the problem since the last time you posted it?

Comment: @anon Yes, I am editing the post at the moment with something I came up with.

Comment: If $M$ has generators $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ and $a_im_i=0$, then what can we say about $a_1\cdots a_k$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm still writing something, give me a minute! :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I updated with my version of the proof. I couldn't come up with an argument to relate $a_1,\dots, a_k$, although I realize they should be related as in the exercise.

Comment: You say "powers of one element." In a group $G$, the notation $\langle g\rangle$ means the subgroup generated by $g$, which equals the set of integer powers of $g$, but in a *ring* $R$, the notation $\langle x\rangle$ means the ideal generated by $x$, which equals the set of all multiples of $x$. Your proof doesn't make sense: the elements of a ring may have a GCD, but what does it mean to talk about the GCD of elements of a *module*? (It doesn't mean anything.)

Comment: As Lord Shark pointed out, every element of $M$ is some combination of $m_1,\cdots,m_k\in M$ and there are nonzero elements $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in D$ such that $a_1m_1=a_2m_2=\cdots=a_km_k=0$. You need to proceed from there.

Comment: The elements $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ are nonzero in $D$, so their product $a_1\cdots a_k$ is a nonzero element of $D$. But you're right to consider it...

Comment: @anon Can we say that $(a_1 \cdots a_k)m_i=0$  $\forall i$? Then $Ann(M)=\langle a_1\cdots a_k \rangle$

Comment: Well, $a_1\cdots a_k\in{\rm Ann}(M)$, although it may not generate it. The point is, from there you can conclude ${\rm Ann}(M)$ is nonzero (so it must be principally generated by a nonzero $a$ since $D$ is a PID),